# Problemas para encontrar posição de string em texto dado?

Tags: c

Eu preciso fazer um programa em C que retorna a posição de uma *string* em um dado texto. A função recebe dois arquivos, um contendo o texto e outro contendo trechos que serão procurados, e retorna um arquivo com as posições de cada trecho.

```
void CtrlF(FILE *arquivo_texto, FILE *arquivo_trechos, FILE *arquivo_saida) {
  char buffer_texto[1000000];
  char *texto, *trecho;

  texto = fgets(buffer_texto, sizeof(buffer_texto), arquivo_texto);
  printf("%s\n", texto);

  while (!feof(arquivo_trechos)) {
    char buffer_trecho[1000000];
    trecho = fgets(buffer_trecho, sizeof(buffer_trecho), arquivo_trechos);
    if (trecho == NULL) {
      break;
    }
    printf("%s\n", trecho);
    int i = 0;
    while (texto[i] != '\0') {
      int j = 0;

      while (trecho[j] != '\0' && texto[i + j] == trecho[j]) {
        j++;
        printf("%d, %d\n", i, i + j - 1);
      }
      if (trecho[j] == '\0') {
        printf("%d, %d\n", i, i + j - 1);
        break;
      }
      i++;
    }
  }
}
```

Para testar, estou fornecendo o arquivo texto com

> Fala pro cliente que o último pull request desse SCRUM superou o desempenho na organização alfanumérico dos arrays multidimensionais. Uma frase intrusa. Desde ontem à noite, a disposição dos elementos HTML complexificou o merge dos parametros passados em funções privadas. Uma frase intrusa.

E o trechos com

> HTML
>
> pull request

E tendo o retorno como

> HTML
>
> 208, 208
>
> 208, 209
>
> 208, 210
>
> 208, 211
>
> pull request
>
> 5, 5
>
> 31, 31
>
> 31, 32
>
> 31, 33
>
> 31, 34
>
> 31, 35
>
> 31, 36
>
> 31, 37
>
> 31, 38
>
> 31, 39
> 31, 40
>
> 31, 41
>
> 31, 42
>
> 58, 58
>
> 71, 71
>
> 184, 184
>
> 216, 216
>
> 239, 239
>
> 250, 250
>
> 272, 272

Pelos retornos, estou tendo três problemas:

1. As posições voltam maiores do que deveriam, por exemplo, sei que HTML está entre 202 e 205, mas retorna 208 a 2011.
2. Ele parece continuar procurando correspondências mesmo depois de terminada a string, pois "pull request" deveria terminar na linha 31 a 42 e de repente está em 272, 272
3. Em momento algum ele imprime os valores do if e não consigo descobrir por que.

Alguém pode me dizer o que estou fazendo de errado?

Answer (score 0):

Depois de mexer um pouco mais no programa eu consegui encontrar o erro. Tinha visto na internet que o final de uma string é interpretado como '\0', mas ao pedir para imprimir os inteiros da string termo a termo notei que sempre tinha os termos 13 e 10 no final. Olhando na [tabela ASCII](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Epattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html) dá pra ver que correspondem a dar enter e começar uma nova linha, respectivamente. Portanto o critério de parada deveria ser, na verdade

```
if (trecho[j] == 13) {
    fprintf(arquivo_saida, "%d, %d\n", i, i + j - 1);
    break;
  }
```

e resolveu todos os três problemas. Caso alguém precise um dia, está aí.